# Is it possible to sell apps on a cryptocurrency exchange?

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoinj

I heard that some cryptocurrencies have their own decentralised exchanges. Is it possible to sell our own apps there and how should that work? Maybe we should implement the cryptocurrency in the app? Otherwise somebody may buy it and sell it again? I am sorry if my question is too simple, I started learning to code 2 months ago and I am full of questions now :)

Comment: I would welcome any feedback, even if it is not a concrete answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like it is possible to be done with NXT Coin
https://nxtforum.org/
http://nxt.org/
Its a decentralized crypto currency. Check their API and the decentralized exchange that it provides. Really interesting possibilities there.